# checking whether an id exists with dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm trying to check whether an html element with a certain id exists before doing some operations on that.

How can I check whether an id exists or not with dojo?

I saw in javascript we can use try catch. But i like a more clean way.

edit:

Doing it like this:

```
 var a = dojo.byId('myId');
 if(a){
     // something
 }
```

Comment: i dont get u right do u mean u need if element exist with given id ?

Comment: what does "id exists" mean: a) an html element with a certain id b) a dijit with a certain id c) a variable with a certain name d) A dance of the voodoo god living behind the moon that categorizes his dances with ids

Comment: Simplify: if (dojo.byId('myId')) { ... }

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In dojo, it's just the same as plain javascript. You should do:

```
var elem = dojo.byId('myId');
 if(elem != null){
     // something
 }
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: nitpick: you can simply do `if (dojo.byId('theId')) { ... }` and achieve the same effect. you don't have to store it in a var or check whether it's equivalent to null.

Comment: Yes, but he wants to use the id inside the if statement.

Answer (score 6):

Use `getElementById()` - it returns null if no element matches, otherwise it returns a reference to the matching element. So:

```
var el = document.getElementById('someid');
if (el != null) {
  // element exists; do something, e.g.,
  alert(el.value);
}
```

(P.S. I don't know how to do it using dojo, but you don't need to...)

Comment: In dojo it is: var aa =  dojo.byId('someId');